# what exactly is an isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

Whenever a problem or question of isomorphism comes up I am clueless as to what they mean. From my understanding an isomorphism is in terms of graph theory where it is the same thing but written a different way. another question I have been curious on is the $⟶$ notation like what exactly does is mean when its  $\Bbb R ⟶ \Bbb R$ or if its $G ⟶ G$ finally the worst one for me to understand is when it goes from one are to another like $ \Bbb R ⟶ \Bbb Q$ or $G ⟶ H$.

Comment: Usually an arrow denotes a *morphism*, or a way of getting from one object to another while preserving structure. Usually objects are sets and morphisms are functions with some special properties.

Answer (score 2):

The question is best answered in terms of category theory.

Recall that a category consists of a collection of objects (denoted with capital letters here) and, for all objects $A$ and $B$, a collection of arrows $A \to B$. The claim that $f$ is an arrow from $A$ to $B$ is written $f : A \to B$.

Note that arrows are also called morphisms.

For each object $A$, there is a designated "identity" arrow $1_A$.

For all objects $A, B, C$, there is a composition operator that takes arrows $g : B \to C$, $f : A \to B$, and outputs an arrow $A \to C$. This arrow is denoted $g \circ f : A \to C$.

Finally, there are some equations that are always satisfied. If $f : A \to B$, then $f \circ 1_A = f = 1_B \circ f$. And if we have arrows $f : A \to B$, $g : B \to C$, and $h : C \to D$, then $h \circ (f \circ g) = (h \circ f) \circ g$.

There are many examples of categories in mathematics. For example, there is a "category of sets", where the objects are sets and the arrows are functions. This is where most of the notation for category theory comes from - often, $f : A \to B$ is interpreted to mean that $f$ is a function with domain $A$ and codomain $B$, which in this case is exactly what it does mean.

There is also a category of groups, where the objects are groups and the arrows are group homomorphisms. To prove this is a category, you need to prove that the identity function $1_G : G \to G$ is actually a group homomorphism and that the composition of group homomorphisms is a group homomorphism.

Similarly, there is a category of rings and ring homomorphisms. There is a category of topological spaces where the arrows are continuous functions. For every field $k$, there is a category of $k$-vector spaces where the arrows are linear functions. There is also a category of graphs. Recall that a (multi)graph is a collection of nodes $V$ together with, for any two nodes $a, b$, a set of edges $E(a, b)$. A graph homomorphism between a graph $(V, E)$ and a graph $(V', E')$ is a function $f : V \to V'$ together with, for each $a, b \in V$, a function $f_{(a, b)} : E(a, b) \to E'(f(a), f(b))$. If you only want to consider simple graphs, you can restrict $E$ so that $E(a, b)$ always has at most 1 element and $E(a, a)$ is always empty to get a "full subcategory" of the category of multigraphs.

There are also many categories where the arrows do not (obviously) correspond to functions (or correspond to very complicated sorts of functions). For example, there is a "matrix category" where the objects are natural numbers, the arrows $n \to m$ are the $n$ by $m$ matrices (with coefficients in the real numbers, say). Arrow composition is matrix multiplication.

For any reflexive, transitive relation $R \subseteq A^2$, there is a corresponding category where the objects are elements of $A$, there is exactly one arrow $x \to y$ if $x R y$, and there is only an arrow from $x$ to $y$ if $x R y$. Usually, we additionally take $R$ to be a partial order.

So what is an isomorphism? An isomorphism is an arrow $f : A \to B$ with a two-sided inverse arrow $g : B \to A$. This means that $f \circ g = 1_B$ and $g \circ f = f_A$.

So an isomorphism in the category of sets is a bijection, an isomorphism in the category of groups/rings/$k$-vector spaces is a group/ring/$k$-vector space isomorphism, an isomorphism in the category of topological spaces is a homeomorphism, and an isomorphism in the category of graphs is a graph isomorphism. An isomorphism within a partial order is an equality.

If there is an isomorphism between two objects, then they are totally indistinguishable from the perspective of category theory. One can show that given any statement made about category theory that does not discuss actual equality of objects (but can discuss equality of parallel arrows $f, g : A \to B$) cannot distinguish between isomorphic objects.

So in other words, isomorphisms mean "equivalent when considering only arrows".

Answer (score 0):

My first graduate math professor gave me an awful definition: "things are isomorphic when they are 'morally equivalent'" which meant nothing to me.  I'll try to do better for you!

Any two objects (mathematical or otherwise) are alike in some ways and different in others.  An isomorphism picks out certain traits of one object, certain traits of the other, and shows that the two objects are the same in that specific way.

Two sets are "isomorphic" when there is a $1-1$ mapping between them, so in this case isomorphism means having the same cardinality--the same number of elements.

Two groups are isomorphic if there is a $1-1$ mapping from the elements of one to the elements of other, AND that preserves the binary operation as well, in that $f(a)**f(b) = f(a*b)$, where the * is the operation in the first group, $a$ and $b$ are elements of the first group, $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are elements of the second group, and ** is the operation on the second group.  Such a mapping "preserves the structure" of the group.  In other words, you can turn one group into the other simply by changing the names of things--which doesn't work for just anything, only for isomorphisms.

Now some groups have automorphisms--isomorphisms onto themselves.  For example, the integers modulo $5$ consist of the equivalence classes $\{[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]\}$.  If you were to map $[1]\rightarrow [3]$, then the rule of isomorphism would require that since $[1]+[1] = [2]$ and $[3]+[3] = [6]=[1]$, then $[2]$ must map to $[1]$.  Likewise you can complete the mapping.  That you *can* complete it shows that the isomorphism (automorphism here) exists.

If you wanted a ring isomorphism, you would need a mapping that not only mapped elements $1-1$, not only satisfied $f(a)**f(b) = f(a*b)$, but *also* satisfied $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$ so that multiplication is "preserved" as well.  Because a ring has a set, and two operations, any isomorphic structure has to have a set of the same size, and two operations, and things have to "line up" to preserve the relationships.

If that is the case, you can essentially relabel one ring (or whatever object) to turn it into the other.  Isomorphic objects are really the same object "in disguise".  The requirements for an isomorphism depends on how complicated the objects are.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different things going on here.  The simpler one is the notation $\to$, which usually means that we in some way, **not necessarily an isomorphism**, mapping one object to another.

An isomorphism is a particular type of map, and we often use the symbol $\cong$ to denote that two objects are isomorphic to one another.  Two objects are isomorphic there is a $1$-$1$ map from one object **onto** the other that preserves all of the structure that we're studying.  That second part is important, but it's often implied from context.

For example, can we say that $\Bbb Z \cong 2 \Bbb Z$?  That depends.  If we're talking about them as groups (with their usual operation), the answer is yes, because there's a $1$-$1$ surjective map that preserves the group operation (addition) and additive inverses.  In other words, $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(-x)=-f(x)$.

But if we're talking about the two structures as rings (with their usual operations), the answer is no because no map can possibly preserve the multiplicative structure.  The first object ($\Bbb Z$) has a multiplicative identity but the second object ($2 \Bbb Z$) does not.  That means there's no way to construct a map $g: \Bbb Z \to 2 \Bbb Z$ such that $g(x)=g(1 \cdot x) = g(1) \cdot g(x)$ because no matter what value in $2 \Bbb Z$ we assign to $g(1)$, it's never the case that for all $x, g(1) \cdot g(x)=g(x)$

Answer (score 0):

You have a pretty good idea of it. Recall the definition of an isomorphism is a bijective mapping $\phi: G_1 \to G_2$ such that for all $x,y \in G_1$,

$$\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y).$$

I’m aware you’ve probably seen this definition, so I include it because of its significance in your understanding of the concept. Note that multiplication inside $\phi$ is the group operation in $G_1$, and the group operation associating the two $\phi$ terms on the RHS is that in $G_2$. This is written differently whether the two groups are additive or multiplicative - for example, if $G_1$‘s operation is additive while the operation in $G_2$ is multiplicative, we write

$$\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)\phi(y).$$

Regardless, we have $\phi(x*y)=\phi(x)•\phi(y)$, where $*$ is the group operation of $G_1$ and $•$ is that of $G_2$.

The main takeaway from an isomorphism between groups is that they consequently have the same Cayley Tables - or if you’re not familiar with those - multiplication tables for their respective group operations. If you make one for $G_1$, the isomorphism tells us one can achieve the Cayley Table for $G_2$ by applying $\phi$ to every element on the Cayley Table of $G_1$.

Because of this, an isomorphism allows many of the group theoretic information known in one group to be valid for another group isomorphic to the original. For example, an isomorphism between groups preserves the number of elements of each order , the number of subgroups, and the cyclic/Abelian/normal structure of these subgroups.

Answer (score 0):

Two things are isomorphic when there is a bijection (A one to one and onto mapping) between the two sets/objects in such a way that every operation of interest is preserved.   In other words, two isomorphic things have the exact same structure with different names.

An example from another field, groups:  If you look at the set of ordered pairs $\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$ with the addition operation adding componentwise mod 2, so $0+0=0=1+1$  and $1+0=0+1=1$,  this is the exact same structure as the set $\{e,a,b,ab\}$  with the rule $a^2=b^2=e$,$ab=ba$, and $ex=xe=x$ for any element $x$.

Here the $(0,0)$ maps to $e$ as the identity element, then we can actually map any of the elements in a one to one and onto mapping between the two sets,  so that adding in the ordered pair names works just like multiplying in the letter sense.

What specific form an isomorphism takes depends on what structures are involved.  For graphs, we want the same number of vertices and that edges are mapped to edges.    Every area of math has its own structures.